# HTML Div Disappears when given Fixed Position

Tags: html, css

Currently I am developing a Facebook like Messenger.  Right now I am working under a chat-area, this thing should be fixed.  But if I give `position:fixed` suddenly `div` disappear.  I don't know what to do.

Here is my HTML/PHP code.

```
   <?php
// Turn off all error reporting

    //shop not login  users from entering 
    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    }else{

    }


require_once("./inc/connect.inc.php");
?>

<header>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home - Copy.css" />
        <nav>
            <h3><a class="h3" href="#">Cp</a></h3>
                <div>        
                        <?php

   //Start your session
   session_start();
   //Read your session (if it is set)
   if (isset($_SESSION['user_login']))
      echo $_SESSION['user_login'];



       ?>

                    </div>
                <div><a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a></div>
                <div><a href="#"><span>Settings </span></a></div>




        </nav>
        <body>
        <div class="shead">
        <div class="a1">       <li   >Frequent Member</li>

             <ul>
                <?php
                    //show all the users expect me
                $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
                    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id!='$user_id'");
                    //display all the results
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
                        echo "<a href='home.php?id={$row['id']}'><p>{$row['username']}</p></a>";
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>




    <div class="a2">      <li >Site's Popular in Your College</li></div>

        </div>
</header>


<div class="rss">

  <?php

  //include('rssclass.php');
  //sinclude('rss.php');

?> 


<div class="message-right">
            <!-- display message -->
            <div class="display-message">
            <?php
                //check $_GET['id'] is set
                if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                    $user_two = trim(mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['id']));
                    //check $user_two is valid
                    $q = mysql_query( "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE id='$user_two' AND id!='$user_id'");
                    //valid $user_two
                    if(mysql_num_rows($q) == 1){
                        //check $user_id and $user_two has conversation or not if no start one
                        $conver = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM  conversation WHERE (user_one='$user_id' AND user_two='$user_two') OR (user_one='$user_two' AND user_two='$user_id')");

                        //they have a conversation
                        if(mysql_num_rows($conver) == 1){
                            //fetch the converstaion id
                            $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($conver);
                            $conversation_id = $fetch['id'];
                        }else{ //they do not have a conversation
                            //start a new converstaion and fetch its id
                            $q = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO `conversation` VALUES ('','$user_id',$user_two)");
                            $conversation_id = mysql_insert_id($con);
                        }
                    }else{
                        die("Invalid $_GET ID.");
                    }
                }else {
                    die("Click On the Person to start Chating.");
                }
            ?>
            </div>

<div class="send-message">
                <!-- store conversation_id, user_from, user_to so that we can send send this values to post_message_ajax.php -->
                <input type="hidden" id="conversation_id" value="<?php echo base64_encode($conversation_id); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="user_form" value="<?php echo base64_encode($user_id); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="user_to" value="<?php echo base64_encode($user_two); ?>">
                <div class="textbox">
                    <input class="t_box" type="text" id="message"  placeholder="Enter Your Message"/>
                    <button class="t_btn" id="reply">Reply</button> 
                <span id="error"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>

            <!--
<div class="textbox">
    <form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="msg_body" class="t_box" id="t_box" >
    <input type="submit" class="t_btn" id="t_btn" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
        </div>-->



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 




</body>
```

Here is my css and .message-right is the element where problem occurs.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic);
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #222;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        text-align: center;
}

header {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #FFD700;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

header > nav > div {
        float: right;
        width: 10.6666%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
}

header > nav > div > a {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        line-height: 50px;
        color: #222;
        transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
        text-transform: uppercase;
}

header > nav > div:hover > a {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        cursor: pointer;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;

}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFD700;
    font-weight: bolder;

}

h3{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: bottom;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;

}
.h3{
    color: #222;
    font-size:25px;
}
.nav{
    position: fixed;
}
 .title-head {

        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:left;
        background-color:#F5F6F7;
        color:#000;
        float: left;
        width: 455.33px;


      }
     .feeds-links {


        text-align:left;
        width: 455.33;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding:5px;
        border:1px solid #dedede;
        padding-top:inherit;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;


      }

.rss{
    float: right;
    padding-top: 100px;

}
.h2{
    color: #000;
    background: #ffd700;
    height: 45px;

    width: 455.33px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);

}
.textarea{
    float: left;
    padding-top:553px; 
    width: 455.3px;
    position: fixed;
}
.t_box{
    float: left;

    border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFD700;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 78%;
    outline: none;
}


.textbox{
    background-color: #FFD700;
  border: 1px solid #FFD700;
  margin-top: 565px;
  padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width:455.5px;
    float: left;



}
.t_btn{
    text-decoration: none;
  color:#222;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
    height: 33px;
    width: 70px;
    outline: none;
}
.shead{
    height: 50px;
    width: 910px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: #FFD700;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    position: sticky;
    border-top: #000;

}
.a1{
    text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
        display: block;
        line-height: 50px;

        color: #000;
        font-size: 19px;
    list-style: none;
    font: #000;



}
.a2{
    text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
        display: block;
        line-height: 50px;
        color: #222;
    float: right;
        transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
    font-size:19px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: -150px;

    list-style: none;
}
.frequentmem{

    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;




}
.message-right{
        margin-right:908px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 615px;
    width:455.5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;

    position: fixed;




}
hr{
    background: #e9e9e9;
    border: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 1px;
}
.message{
    width: 455.3px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 8px 24px;


}
```

Comment: PHP is server side it will generate content but doesn't actual affect the output/display. The issue would be with your CSS or generated HTML. You might want to add the relevant HTML to this.

Comment: You should add all of the relevant html. You can pull the source from the browser.

Comment: What is mean by relevant html ?

Comment: provide the compiled/rendered html

Comment: Yes there it is. @harmlessdragon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

float:left doesn't do anything if your position is fixed, you should add left:0 instead, on the other hand, you should always specify vertical and horizontal position of a fixed element unless you want it to stay on the part of the page it was rendered this means if your message-right are is rendered below the fold it will not be visible to your users unless you tell it at what coordinates it should remain fixed

Answer (score 1):

I think floating divs and fixing the position do not go well together.

Try removing the float:left and as the user above suggested, adding the left: some_pixels, top: some_pixels to align the div "absolutely" on the page. I usually add a border/background color to divs to identify where they are on the page (then remove later), so you can try that to to make sure it is where you expect it to be.

```
.message-right{
        margin-right:908px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 615px;
    width:455.5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    **float: left;** <-- remove
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a fixed position, maybe your div is behind some other content. Have you tried using a [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) ? Setting the z-index to 1 would move it forward over another div. Also, you have no top, bottom, right or left dimensions for your fixed position. You could try moving the div around by assigning those values. [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed). 
Anyways, it is hard to tell what your problem is without the HTML to go with the CSS. Posting that would help you get better response.
I don't have 50 reputation, so I had to add this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine. Adding a border should do the trick.For instance:
But without the rest of the code(html and css) it would be hard to know what is wrong.

```
.chat-area{
    margin-right:908px;
    background: #fff;
    border:1px solid black;<-- like this
    height: 615px;
    width:455.5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}
```